# JBoss 12 Project with LDAP

Tags: authentication, server, jboss, ldap

Can somebody give a guideline about how to create a project with STRUTS 2(no hibernate) in JBOSS 12 to use LDAP login? If you can give more details about the configuration in the project as well as on the server and the mechanism why I have to do that way, that will be great. I've searched the web, but did not find the one I want. Is there any tutorial? I use JBOSS AS 7.2 server. I am migrating an AS 5 STRUTS 1 project to JBOSS 12 running AS7.2, but it did not do any authorization and no error message for me to debug.

Comment: I do not see any code in the original project in handling login and password but login page appears and verifies credentials and then direct to home. After I check it out to JBOBB 12, it always direct to
 <error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/unauthorized.html</location>
 </error-page>
specified in web.xml without any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I use JBOSS 12.9.0GA. Originally, in WEB-INF/web.xml, it is:

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>            
</auth-constraint>
```

I changed to

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Your_Role_Name_1</role-name> 
    <role-name>Your_Role_Name_2</role-name> 
    <role-name>Your_Role_Name_3</role-name>         
</auth-constraint>
```

It worked!